# BGE GLSL materials in embedded player

Tags: materials, game-engine, shaders

I am on the very beginning of creating a game. As a GE BGE was chosen. At the moment a problem popped out: I want to use real-time shadows and when I set Shading to GLSL in the Render options I get just absolutely white objects. No changes to materials take effect, no shadows are visible. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: I found out that it works properly in the standalone player. Can I make it work in embedded player as well?**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the viewport is set to *textured* shading in *3D view > Header* before starting the game engine:

[image]

The viewport shading will affect the shading used in the game engine to some degree.

Wireframe:

[image]

Solid:

[image]

Texture:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what you need to do.